# Setting version of dotnet core project when using Team City and Octopus Deploy?

Tags: teamcity, .net-core, octopus-deploy

I have a dotnet core project that I want to build and deploy.

Currently I have three steps in TC;

- dotnet restore
- dotnet pack
- octopus deploy: push

In OD I wish to use the version which is stamped into the package that OD receives in build-in repository.

It almost works!

However!

TC always builds to a file like Ajf.IdentityServer.1.0.0-54.nupkg (step 2, dotnet pack).

The step 2, dotnet pack, has an option - Version Suffix - where I'm currently using %build.counter%.

I want the version to be formed as 1.0.0.54, not 1.0.0-54.

Apparently, there's no problem in OD (I can deploy those malformed versions), but it just feels... wrong?

How can I stamp my versions with the 'right' version as calculated by TC?

Thanks! ;)

Comment: There's an easier way to do this now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can introduce an additional property to use in MSBuild.

If you modify your csproj to set the version like this to introduce a custom `BuildNumber` property which defaults to `0`:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <BuildNumber Condition="'$(BuildNumber)' == ''">0</BuildNumber>
  <VersionPrefix>1.2.3.$(BuildNumber)</VersionPrefix>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Then you can pass `BuildNumber` as an additional parameter to all relevant `dotnet` invocations:

```
dotnet pack -c Release /p:BuildNumber=%build.counter%
```

Comment: Upvoted, but for some reason it hasn't changed the version number. TeamCity just creates 1.2.0, rather than 1.2.%build.number%.

Comment: But there is another way to do it. I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: Works like a charm here. You sure build.number is actually anything else than 0?

Answer (score 2):

As of now, the easiest way to achieve this is

```
/p:PackageVersion=1.2.%build.number%
```

The advantage of this is that you don't have to modify your csproj file in inay way.

Comment: It just doesn't set the assembly versions and requires the build definition to contain the `1.2` part if that is okay.